Getting error as TypeError: typeorm_1.DataSource is not a constructor while exporting it from lib to other project
Getting error as TypeError: typeorm_1.DataSource is not a constructor when try to export from lib project and use in other project.
Basically am upgrading Nodejs, Typeorm and Typescript to latest stable version.
Typeorm => Old: 0.2.45, New: 0.3.20
Typescript => Old: 4.5.5, New 5.5.3
Lib project tsconfig Look like
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es5", "es6", "dom", "ES2023"],
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "ES2022",
    "declaration": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "./lib",    
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/__tests__/*", "src/app.ts"]
}

Actual error came here:
export const AppDataSourcePg = new DataSource();

when i try to export AppDataSourcePg and import on other places.
